# site get login attempts after htaccess ip restriction

Tags: security

I'm using a security plugin that keep sending me emails:

"A lockdown event has occurred due to too many failed login attempts or invalid username:
Username: Admin
IP Address: 195.154.243.31

IP Range: 195.154.243.*

Log into your site's WordPress administration panel to see the duration of the lockout or to unlock the user."

I tried to block the access to wp-admin folder and create htaccess file with this code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <my ip>
```

also in the root htaccess i added :

```
<Files ~ "(wp-login.php|wp-signup.php)">
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from <my ip>
</Files>
```

how does the attacker/bot try to login?

Comment: Most likely via xmlrpc.php

Comment: @birgire thanks ill try to add add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false'); to wp-config.php and c how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @birgire suggest I added

`add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');`

to wp-config.php

and no attacker/bot tries to login anymore

Answer (score 0):

@birgire has a right answer

And they can use [WPScan](http://wpscan.org/) for example, with a brute force attack on wp-login.php

I recommand to rename your login page, you can do it manually or with a plugin.

Comment: but how they can get to login after i limited the access to my ip only?

Comment: yes sorry I didn't see very weel your htaccess. Indeed, they can't try anything with your htaccess.

Comment: they do c @birgire suggestion and that was the problem